# Putty: Incoming Packet was garbled on decryption

Tags: ssh, centos6, putty

I am unable to connect to my server on my local network (VM).

I have multiple servers I am able to connect to.

When I try to putty into the server, I get the message

```
Incoming Packet was garbled on decryption
```

What I've tried:

I googled and tried to implement their solution -- force blowfish and ssh2. Still does not work.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had this problem. This is what I did to fix it:

Download latest version of PuTTY (I was using 0.62 instead of 0.63)
In PuTTY configuration, go to Connection->SSH and move "Blowfish" to the top of the list under "Encryption cipher selection policy".

Comment: Why does this work though? lol

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem "Incoming Packet was garbled on decryption".

for  the connection i used:

```
> putty.exe -proxycmd "plink.exe john@81.163.163.63 -P 22 -nc 10.10.10.10:22 -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\id.ppk " john@10.10.10.10  -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\john.ppk
```

the solution=> First of all launch "plink" part of the command:

```
> plink.exe john@81.163.163.63 -P 22 -nc 10.10.10.10:22 -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\id.ppk
```

it will ask "the server host key is not cached". Just click "yes", "yes" etc.

After that launch full command:

```
>putty.exe -proxycmd "plink.exe john@81.163.163.63 -P 22 -nc 10.10.10.10:22 -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\id.ppk " john@10.10.10.10  -i c:\Users\john\.ssh\john.ppk
```

in my case it solved the problem.